# Reservation value on united.com cancellation page = refund value?

Tags: bookings, united-airlines, refunds

This seems like an extremely basic question, yet after quite some research the only relevant info I found was that I should have saved a PDF of the fare terms provided only once during the reservation process.

Through a Google Flights alert I found that the multi-stop ticket I bought a few weeks ago on united.com is now available at a lower price, and while I strongly suspect that the fare I bought is non-refundable (at least not fully; due to its already quite low price), I would like to make sure that I indeed wouldn't save money cancelling the ticket and then buying it again.

On the cancellation page, the sum I paid for the ticket is displayed in green as "reservation value", above "credit towards" options for what one could assume might possibly be a refund. Conspicuously absent is a clear indication that any of this does in fact guarantee a refund of the sum displayed – **is there any way to find out in advance if my ticket can be refunded, and if so, what the penalty would be**?

[image: cancellation page screenshot]

Comment: Yes. Pick up a phone and call them. They have the information

Comment: You should have an e-ticket (either sent by e-mail, or available via the manage my booking section on the site). That should show the fare code and/or the cancellation terms. Also, what do you get when you click on "View Receipt"?

Comment: @jcaron: The fare class is L, according to united.com. My receipt (email and on united.com) only includes non-specific refund information ("If you have purchased a restricted ticket, depending on the rules applicable to the fare paid, one or more restrictions including, but not limited to, the following may apply to your travel" etc.) and details on 24-hour returns.

Comment: Do you have a more specific fare code, not just the letter? Something like LAA7AHDS. Can you also provide the city pair? You can start the booking process on the UA site, select a fare class, and view fare rules.

Comment: @jcaron VIE–EWR and EWR–PBI (outbound) and EWR–VIE (inbound). Somehow can't seem to find a fare code, neither on the receipt nor on the trip details page on united.com …

Comment: Found a LLXNCPD2 fare code, and that seems to say it's not refundable, but you need aspirin to decipher the whole penalties section. Did you not receive an e-ticket or receipt with all the details of your flights, taxes, etc?

Comment: @jcaron I received an "eTicket Itinerary and Receipt for Confirmation [confirmation code]", which seems identical to the receipt provided on united.com. It includes flight details, a "fare breakdown" (taxes etc.) as well as (very) general "Fare rules" ("Additional charges may apply for changes in addition to any fare rules listed."). I guess I could share a redacted version of that email? (Not sure about the best way to do that.)

Comment: Somewhere in there you should probably have the full fare basis code (it's usually 5-10 letters/digits, starting with the fare class). There should be one for each leg. It does seem that L fares are generally not refundable, but there might be an exception in one of the various fare codes.

Comment: @jcaron I just went through all 51 Cmd+F results for " L", there's no fare basis code. I guess this can't possibly have anything to do with the fact that two of the three legs (the first and the last) are operated by Austrian Airlines?

Comment: Not all airlines show full fare codes on e-tickets/receipts, which is quite a shame, as it's usually the only way (other than contacting them) to find the full fare rules.

Comment: I guess I'll indeed have to call them. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Back before the Continental merger, United would not only refund the fare difference with a voucher, but provided a button on the reservation screen of the website where you could request it, even if the amount was only $10. This was one of the vanishingly rare spots where United's customer service was an industry leader, but alas, this feature was later hidden and did not return after the conversion to Continental's IT systems, despite CO's supposedly more customer-oriented culture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I called United, and after several minutes of them "researching" my fare terms they could finally tell me that there is a penalty (in my case slightly higher than what I would have saved buying the ticket at the current lower price), i.e. the value displayed on the cancellation page is *not* the refund amount.

When – out of pure curiosity – I asked about my fare basis code, they told me that I would have to be put on hold so that they could "investigate" it (for which I sadly didn't have time).